# Using tkinter compare multiple csv and display the matching

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

**New to Tkinter**

I have a json file which contains some Firewall-rules, then convert it into two different csvs. As the firewall-rules have two different sets with ARules.csv and YRules.csv Don't want to merge it because of the requirement.

Then using splunk we pull the stats which will generate firewall-rules for that day. We then export it with the name - logReport.csv. Let's say there are 50 rows of data

check the results of logReport (data) is present in both the csvs[ARules(150 rows) and YRules(100 rows)]

```
    ARules.loc[ARules['name'].isin(logReport['data'])]  - [result - 30]
    YRules.loc[YRules['name'].isin(logReport['data'])]  - [result - 20]
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to create a process, where I call the api, and convert that JSON into multiple csv and display it in "tkinter" in two different frames one for ARules and other for YRules, then ask the user to import that logReport.csv using "filedialog or opencsv" and then get the matching/difference results and export it to csv.

my code

```
import pandas as pd
import json
f = open("/Users/Documents/Info/data.json")
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
ARules = pd.DataFrame(data['ARules'])
YRules = pd.DataFrame(data['YRules'])

csvfile = "/Users/Downloads/logReport.csv"
logReport = pd.read_csv(csvfile,error_bad_lines=False, engine="python")

ARulesV1 = ARules.loc[ARules['ARules'].isin(logReport['data'])]
YRulesV1 = XRules.loc[XRules['YRules'].isin(logReport['data'])]
```

I was able to do this much but not able to display the output on GUI.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import json,os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

def import_csv_data():
    global v
    csv_file_path = askopenfilename()
    v.set(csv_file_path)
    colnames=['rules', 'count'] 
    logReport = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(csv_file_path,error_bad_lines=False,names=colnames, header=None, engine="python"))
    logReport.drop(logReport.index[0],inplace=True)
    search(logReport)

def search(logReport):
    f = open("/Users/Documents/Info/data.json")
    data = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    ARules = pd.DataFrame(data['ARules'])
    YRules = pd.DataFrame(data['YRules'])
    print("Total Number of ARules:",ARules.shape[0])
    print("Total Number of YRules:",YRules.shape[0])
    print()
    print("Stats Report from Splunk:",logReport.shape[0])
    print("Number of Rules Triggered in ARules:",ARules.loc[ARules['name'].isin(logReport['data'])].shape[0])
    print("Number of Rules Triggered in YRules:",YRules.loc[YRules['name'].isin(logReport['data'])].shape[0])

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Search CSV")
frame = Frame(window, width=500, height=500)
frame.pack()

tk.Label(frame, text='File Path').grid(row=0, column=0)
v = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=v,width=30).grid(row=0, column=1)

tk.Button(frame, text='Browse',command=import_csv_data).grid(row=1, column=0)

lbl3 = tk.Label(frame, text = "Total Number of Rules: ").grid(row = 3, column = 1)


window.mainloop()
```

Want to display the print details on GUI

Comment: If you want to display a table, you might have better luck using PyQt.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import json,os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile

def import_csv_data():
    global v,csvData
    csv_file_path = askopenfilename()
    v.set(csv_file_path)
    colnames=['rules', 'count'] 
    csvData = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(csv_file_path,error_bad_lines=False,names=colnames, header=None, engine="python"))
    csvData.drop(csvData.index[0],inplace=True)
    search()

def loadJson():
    global data
    name = askopenfilename(initialdir="../Path/For/JSON_file",
                           filetypes=(("Json File", "*.json"), ("All Files", "*.*")),
                           title="Choose a file."
                           )
    try:
        f = open(name)
        data = json.load(f)
        f.close()
    except Exception:
        messagebox.showerror("Error Message", 'File Corrupted’)

def search():
    global Adata, Ydata
    Adata = pd.DataFrame(data['Arules'])
    Ydata = pd.DataFrame(data['Yrules'])

    adata.config(text=Adata.shape[0])
    ydata.config(text=Ydata.shape[0])
    tData.config(text=csvData.shape[0])
    AResult.config(text=Adata.loc[Adata['name'].isin(csvData['rules'])].shape[0])
    YResult.config(text=Ydata.loc[Ydata['name'].isin(csvData['rules'])].shape[0])
    
def write_to_csv():
    notTriggered = Adata['name'].loc[~Adata['name'].isin(csvData['rules'])]
    notTriggered2 = Ydata['name'].loc[~Ydata['name'].isin(csvData['rules'])]
    bigResult = notTriggered.append(notTriggered2, ignore_index=True)
    name = asksaveasfile(initialfile = 'Untitled.csv’,mode='w',
defaultextension=".csv",filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"),("Text Documents","*.txt")])
    if name:
        bigResult.to_csv(name)
        name.close()   

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Search Match Alerts“)
frame = Frame(window, width=500, height=500)
frame.pack()

tk.Label(frame, text='File Path').grid(row=1, column=0)
v = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=v,width=40).grid(row=1, column=1)

tk.Button(frame, text='Import Json',command=loadJson).grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(frame, text='Browse',command=import_csv_data).grid(row=2, column=0)
tk.Button(frame, text='Export',command=write_to_csv).grid(row=2, column=3)

font1 = ("Arial", 14)
tk.Label(frame, text = "Total Number of ARules: ").grid(row = 3, column = 0)
adata = Label(frame, font=font1)
adata.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

tk.Label(frame, text = "Total Number of YRules: ").grid(row = 4, column = 0)
ydata = Label(frame, font=font1)
ydata.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)

tk.Label(frame, text = "Stats Report from Splunk: ").grid(row = 5, column = 0)
tData = Label(frame, font=font1)
tData.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)

tk.Label(frame, text = "No. of Match Result on ARules: ").grid(row = 6, column = 0)
AResult = Label(frame, font=font1)
AResult.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)

tk.Label(frame, text = "No. of Match Result on YRules: ").grid(row = 7, column = 0)
YResult = Label(frame, font=font1)
YResult.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)


window.mainloop()
```